# assign indexes of 2 strings in loop C#

Tags: c#

I need to assign all indexes from one string to all indexes of another string.
I think its the best to make a for loop.

```
string stdalph = "apple";
string ourkey = "cream";
StringBuilder sbalph = new StringBuilder(stdalph);
StringBuilder sbkey = new StringBuilder(ourkey);
```

So like index of 'a' = index of 'c'

```
sbalph[0] = sbkey[0];
sbalph[1] = sbkey[1];
```

and so on

Would appreciate any help
// edit

ye but whats actually I need to perform is

```
string stdalph = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456‌​789"; 
string ourkey = "xMK6JDC18hLoYeEkBSlIyVO0niadRf9qH5N4tbWpZ3wgAuc7GQjXm2FUvTz‌​Prs"; 
StringBuilder sbalph = new StringBuilder(stdalph); 
StringBuilder sbkey = new StringBuilder(ourkey); 
textBox2.Text = textBox1.Text;
```

and for example I write 'abc' and it translates it to 'xMK'

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: I don't get what you mean. `sbalph[0] = sbkey[0]` etc. would just copy the string.

Comment: So you want to `Array.Copy()`?

Comment: I need to perform this 62 times cuz my strings consists of 62 letters for(int i=0; i<63; i++) {

                sbalph[0] = sbkey[0];
            }

Comment: Why not just write `sbalph = sbkey`?

Comment: "I need to assign all indexes from one string to all indexes of another string." I don't think this is what you actually want. This would increases the number of assignments exponentially as your string lengths increase.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Wrong. The indexer of `StringBuilder`allows write access too

Comment: because I need to assign indexes, not strings

Comment: @syset: but the result is a string that is the same as the second string `"cream"`. With one exception, the first string has not the same length.

Comment: @adjan Ah, you´re right. Did not see it was a `StringBuilder`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter but they are the same length (5)

Comment: described my question again @all

Comment: Finally, I see what you're trying to do. It's called a [Substitution Cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_cipher).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a for-loop you would normally use:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Math.Min(sbalph.Length, sbkey.Length); i++)
{
    sbalph[i] = sbkey[i];
}
```

But the requirement isn't very clear. It seems you are assigning the second `StringBuilder` to the first `StringBuilder`, so why not simply:

```
sbalph = new StringBuilder(sbkey.ToString());
```